# Different results for every cloud compare aligning module

Tags: cad

I have tried [cloudcompare](http://www.danielgm.net/cc/) and the [aligning](https://www.cloudcompare.org/doc/wiki/index.php?title=ICP) ICP module like this:

[image]

and give transformation matrix lie this:

[image]

For one **STL** file twice and get different result for under 0.1 value in max distance like show at below pictures:

first one :
[image]

Second aligning try:

[image]
The above **cloud compare** bin file could be acceptable from [here](https://gofile.io/d/TJKGvN).
so i like to know why this difference in results happen? does every time which i use align module it create different transformation matrix ?

Question asked also here:

https://www.cloudcompare.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=4625

**Update:**

My guess is that happens because of **difference** between The reference STL points and the aligned target points, which  here for reference is almost 26,000 point and target almost 200,000 point. which needs to select random point based of reference points in target STL file for aligning.

Thanks.